Broken dns resolver on Arm Mac for docker container
We have setup a .devcontainer environment for the following services

azure db
.Net Aspire AppHost
Asp.Net Core WebApi
Angular-Client

The AppHost and the WebApis are working fine. When we try to browse to the Angular Client (on M-Chip Macs), the host resolves localhost to ::1 (ipv6 loopback) and the browser displays 403. The AppHost and WebApis are resolved to 127.0.0.1 and work as expected.
The Applications are working as expected on a

Windows 11 machine with docker v4.31.1
Mac (Intel) latest docker

They are not working on

Mac M1 macOS 14.5 (23F79), docker 4.31.0 (Engine: 26.1.4)
Mac M2 ?

We have a pre-built docker image with the following Dockerfile:
# [Choice] .NET version: 8.0-bookworm, 8.0-jammy, 8.0-bullseye
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/dotnet:1-8.0-bookworm

# Add .NET global tools path
ENV PATH $PATH:/home/vscode/.dotnet:/home/vscode/.dotnet/tools

# [Optional] Uncomment this section to install additional OS packages.
RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends software-properties-common

# Install SQL Tools: SQLPackage and sqlcmd
COPY sql/installSQLtools.sh installSQLtools.sh
RUN bash ./installSQLtools.sh \
     && apt-get clean -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/library-scripts

and this devcontainer.json:
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. 
// For config options, see the README at: https://github.com/microsoft/azuresql-devcontainers/tree/main/src/dotnet-aspire
{
    "name": ".NET with Aspire and Azure SQL",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "./Dockerfile",
        "context": "."
    },
    // Features to add to the dev container. More info: https://containers.dev/features.
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/azure-cli:1": {
            "installBicep": true,
            "installUsingPython": true,
            "version": "latest"
        },
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/docker-outside-of-docker:1": {
            "version": "latest"
        },
        "ghcr.io/azure/azure-dev/azd:latest": {
            "version": "latest"
        },
        // "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/node": {
        //  "version": "latest"
        // },
        "ghcr.io/nullcoder/devcontainer-features/stripe-cli": {
            "version": "latest"
        },
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/angular-cli": {
            "version": "^17.0.0"
        }
    },
    // Uncomment to connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/dev-containers-non-root.
    // "remoteUser": "root"
    // "remoteUser": "vscode"
}

Our actual devcontainer consists of the following docker-compose.yml:
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    volumes:
      - ..:/workspace:cached

    # Overrides default command so things don't shut down after the process ends.
    command: sleep infinity

    # Runs app on the same network as the database container, allows "forwardPorts" in devcontainer.json function.
    network_mode: service:db
    # Uncomment the next line to use a non-root user for all processes.
    # user: vscode

    # Use "forwardPorts" in **devcontainer.json** to forward an app port locally. 
    # (Adding the "ports" property to this file will not forward from a Codespace.)

  db:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    hostname: Platform-SQL-Library
    container_name: Platform-SQL-Library
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
    env_file:
      - .env
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: 2048M
    # Add "forwardPorts": ["1433"] to **devcontainer.json** to forward MSSQL locally.
    # (Adding the "ports" property to this file will not forward from a Codespace.)

And this Dockerfile:
FROM ***.azurecr.io/devcontainers/platform

# # Install SQL Tools: SQLPackage and sqlcmd
# COPY dotnet/installDotnetTools.sh installDotnetTools.sh
# RUN bash ./installDotnetTools.sh \
#     && apt-get clean -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/library-scripts

# Set environment variable
ENV ASPIRE_ALLOW_UNSECURED_TRANSPORT=true

# Update .NET workload and install .NET Aspire
RUN dotnet workload update
RUN dotnet workload install aspire
RUN sed -i "s|DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2|DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1|g" /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

This is the AppHost's Program.cs
var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// var sql = builder.AddSqlServer("sql");
// var sqldb = sql.AddDatabase("sqldb");

var apiService = builder.AddProject<Projects.Platform_ApiService>("apiservice")
    .WithExternalHttpEndpoints();

builder.AddNpmApp("angularClients", "../Clients/AngularClients")
    .WithReference(apiService)
    .WithHttpEndpoint(env: "PORT",port: 5000)
    .WithExternalHttpEndpoints()
    .PublishAsDockerFile();

builder.Build().Run();

Our devcontainer setup is still a bit work in progress. Any suggestions for improvement welcome!

localhost is resolving to both ::1 (IPv6) and 127.0.0.1 (IPv4), as it should. Since the specified host name has both IPv6 and IPv4 addresses, many clients will use the "happy eyeballs" approach of trying to connect to both, and going with whichever responds fastest. If you have the port open on IPv4, but closed on IPv6, that means you have a race condition (i.e. it's not deterministic) whether you get a connection or a rejection. The solution is to either serve on IPv6 as well as IPv4, or use a domain name that only resolves to IPv4.

@GordonDavisson I can see all the forwarded ports in vs code, and they all look the same. How can I make sure that the desired port (5000) is available for both, ipv4 and ipv6?

I'm not familiar enough with either VS Code or docker to help much, but I think the two main things you need to check are: 1) is the IPv6 port getting forwarded to the container along with the IPv4 port, and 2) is the service running in the container listening for both IPv4 and IPv6 connections (if it's not, the host OS will be forwarding to a closed port, giving the same result as if it wasn't forwarded at all).
